# How to set C++11 in CodeBlocks on Windows 7

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I've installed Code Blocks on Windows 7. I cannot choose C++11 options. I saw a lot of tutorials. In each of them in "Global compiler settings" there were options to choose (in such order):

```
//have g++ follow the 1998 standard [...]
//have g++ follow the coming c++0x standard [...]
//have g++ follow the C++11 ISO standard [...]
```

In my version of CodeBlocks, the third option is missing.

Comment: That CodeBlocks dialog box includes an option to add any settings that you want.

Comment: Then how about updating your CodeBlocks? Because I have this option on latest version. Or, as DrewDormann suggested, add this option manually (the command is `-std=c++11`).

Comment: As I recall, 10.05 did not include `-std=c++11` in the given list, only `-std=c++0x`, and 12.11, or whatever the next version is, does.

Comment: Nothing works. Program doesn't accept adding -std=c++11. My version is 13.12.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to:

```
Project => Build Options => Compiler Settings tab => Other Options and enter '-std=c++11'
```

Alternatively you can go to:

```
Settings => Compilers => Select GNU GCC Compiler => Other Options => -std=c++11
```

If that doesn't work download the latest GCC / MinGW Compiler and go to:

```
Settings => Compilers => Select GNU GCC Compiler => Toolchain executables =>
Either AutoDetect or enter the path to the compiler folder =>
Save => Check again if the "g++ follow the C++11 ISO standard" is there
```

Comment: Nothing works. Program doesn't accept adding -std=c++11. My version is 13.12.

Comment: @AntoniBąk what compiler are you using? all I can think of is that your compiler might not support c++11

Comment: It's GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: @AntoniBąk is every field filled in Toolchain executables?